# Combining data from 2 tables in to 1 dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, dynamicquery

I have two tables:

```
table 1
id    item     itemType 
-----------------------
1     book1    1
2     book2    1
3     laptop1  2

table 2
id    itemId    name    value
------------------------------------------
1     1         author  enid blyton
2     1         title   five 1
3     2         author  enid blyton
4     2         title   five 2
5     3         cpu     i7-940
6     3         ram     4 GB
7     3         vcard   nvidia quadro
```

When I query with filter itemType = 1, the result should be:

```
query 1
id    item    author          title
--------------------------------------------------------
1     book1   enid blyton     five 1
2     book2   enid blyton     five 2
```

and with filter itemType = 2

```
query 2
id    item       cpu       ram        vcard
----------------------------------------------
1     laptop1    i7-940    4 GB       nvidia quadro
```

and without filter

```
query 3
id    item    author          title      cpu       ram         vcard
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     book1   enid blyton     five 1
2     book2   enid blyton     five 2
1     laptop1                            i7-940    4 GB        nvidia quadro
```

The reason I use table 2 is because the parameter of each itemType is created during the fly, so it is not possible to have a table like in query 3.

At this moment I can solve this in C# by rebuilding the table programmatically (using a lot of linq call). With a small size of table 1 (1K rows) and 2 (10K rows), the performance is good, but now the size of table 1 is already more than 100K rows and table 2 is more than 1M rows, and the performance is very low.

Is there any function using SQL query that can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly dynamic but **if your name's are all known upfront**, you can use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) to retrieve your data.

> PIVOT rotates a table-valued expression by turning the unique values
>   from one column in the expression into multiple columns in the output,
>   and performs aggregations where they are required on any remaining
>   column values that are wanted in the final output.

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  t1.Id
        , t1.item
        , t2.author
        , t2.title
        , t2.cpu
        , t2.ram
        , t2.vcard
FROM    table1 t1
        INNER JOIN (        
          SELECT  *
          FROM    (
                    SELECT  itemId
                            , name
                            , value 
                    FROM    table2
                  ) s
                  PIVOT (
                    MAX(Value) 
                    FOR name IN (title, author, cpu, ram, vcard)
                  ) p
        ) t2 ON t2.itemId = t1.Id
```

#### Test script

```
;WITH table1 (id, item, itemtype) AS (
    SELECT 1, 'book1', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'book2', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'laptop1', 2
)
, table2 (id, itemId, name, value) AS (
    SELECT 1, 1, 'author', 'enid blyton'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1, 'title', 'five 1'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 2, 'author', 'enid blyton'
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 2, 'title', 'five 2'
    UNION ALL SELECT 5, 3, 'cpu', 'i7 940'
    UNION ALL SELECT 6, 3, 'ram', '4 GB'
    UNION ALL SELECT 7, 3, 'vcard', 'nvidia quadro'
)
SELECT  t1.Id
        , t1.item
        , t2.author
        , t2.title
        , t2.cpu
        , t2.ram
        , t2.vcard
FROM    table1 t1
        INNER JOIN (        
          SELECT  *
          FROM    (
                    SELECT  itemId
                            , name
                            , value 
                    FROM    table2
                  ) s
                  PIVOT (
                    MAX(Value) 
                    FOR name IN (title, author, cpu, ram, vcard)
                  ) p
        ) t2 ON t2.itemId = t1.Id
```

Comment: Should probably include t1.itemtype in either the main select or a where clause. This answer assumes that all potential table2 names are known when writing the query.

Comment: @Mark Bannister - You are probably right if OP wants to filter on that. As for your other concern, that was mentioned in the answer. I have emphasized it to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest running a query to return all possible names from table2 for the specified itemtype, like so:

```
select distinct name
from table2 t2
where exists (select null
              from table1 t1
              where t1.itemtype = @itemtype and
                    t1.id = t2.item_id)
```

In C#, concatenate the names into a single comma-separated string, then construct a new query string similar to Lieven's answer, like so:

```
SELECT  t1.item
        , t2.*
FROM    table1 t1
        INNER JOIN (SELECT  *
                    FROM    (SELECT  itemId,
                                     name,
                                     value 
                             FROM    table2) s
                            PIVOT (MAX(Value) 
                                   FOR name IN (/*insert names string here*/)) p
                   ) t2 ON t2.itemId = t1.Id
WHERE t1.itemtype = @itemtype;
```

(with the names string replacing the comment inside the brackets).

Incidentally, if possible, I suggest separating the names from Table 2 into a separate lookup table, like so:

```
name_table
----------
name_id
name
itemtype
```

- this would mean that the first query would only have to query a small lookup table rather than all of table 2; it could also be used for consistency in name values at data entry.